# AWS DynamoDB fails at The provided key element does not match the schema because of CSV format

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on importing data from S3 bucket to DynamoDB using datapipeline. The data is in csv format. I have been struggling with this for a week now, and finally came to know the real problem.
I have some fields, the important ones are `(id (partitionKey), username (sortKey))` .
Now one of the entry in data is `username` has been set as a comma seperated value. ForExample: `{"username": ""someuser,name"}` . Now the irony of csv file is when mapping to dynamodb through csv (comma seperated) file. It takes comma as a new entry in the column. And so, it fails with the error  `The provided key element does not match the schema`. Which will ofcourse right.

Is there any way I can overcome this issue? Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

**EDIT:**
The csv entry looks like this as an example.

```
1234567,"user,name",$123$,some@email.de,2002-05-28 14:07:04.0,2013-07-19 14:17:05.0,2020-02-19 15:32:18.611,2014-02-27 14:49:19.0,,,,
```

Comment: Are the fields with a comma quoted? Can you please provide a few sample lines *exactly* as they appear in the CSV?

Comment: How are you importing the data into DynamoDB exactly? I'm not aware of an AWS service that does this for you automatically without having to write some code.

Comment: @MarkB I am using datapipeline to transfer data from s3 to dynamodb. I am using cloudformation templates for that.